# What is the difference between internally div and semantic elements like section or article etc..?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

What is the difference between internally for `div` and semantic elements like `section` or `article` etc.?

I found that internally `div` also have `display: block;` and semantic elements are also have (`section`, `article` etc.) `display: block;`, so internally both CSS is same, so semantics are just to present HTML code meaningfully or is there anything else internal behaviour?

I know that for `div` element there is no meaning but semantics elements have meaningful name.

Comment: Not necessarily behaviour, but for organization IMO. From MDN: "Do not use the <section> element as a generic container; this is what <div> is for, especially when the sectioning is only for styling purposes. A rule of thumb is that a section should logically appear in the outline of a document." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section

Comment: What do you mean by "internally"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fully support @TFFX answer, I just want to add another aspect, namely Screenreaders for blind people. They work in a way that they not only read the contents (which is the only thing seeing users would normally see), but they also read the HTML-tags inside the body-tag. So for blind people it is easier to understand a webpage when there are different tags in use.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/  they give a clear guide to html5.

> section is a blob of content that you could store as an individual record in a database. 
>   It generally looks like this (and note that the heading goes inside the section element, not immediately before it):

```
<body>
...
  <section>
    <h2>level of heading = section nesting level</h2>
      rest of the content
  </section>
...
</body>
```